# How to create Aircraft Seat Map View in Flutter (DART)with Hover Container?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Seat Map:

[image]

I need to blue color container scrollable horizontally and left to right

```
Container(
          width: 400,
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 50,
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  ),
                ),
                GridView.builder(
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 7,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 2,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 2),
                  itemCount: seatCount,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    if (index == 3) {
                      localIndex = index + 7;
                      return SeatMapContainer(
                        seatMapColor: Colors.transparent,
                      );
                    } else if (localIndex != 0 && localIndex == index) {
                      localIndex = localIndex + 7;
                      return SeatMapContainer(
                        seatMapColor: Colors.transparent,
                      );
                    } else {
                      return const SeatMapContainer();
                    }
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Comment: @JamesZ Please check image.